# How can I put two queries in one mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
mysql_query("
  UPDATE name SET money = money + 1;
  UPDATE surname SET money = money + 1;
");
```

but it doesn't work.

It's just example, but my question is: How can I put two or even more queries in one `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/mysql_query says:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (*multiple queries are not supported*) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier .

But you might be interested in [mysql**i**::multi_query](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query):

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

You should use transactions for queries that need to happen in an atomic fashion, which I suspect these may.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the MySQLi interface, mysqli_multi_query() in particular.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

It should be noted that you need to be extra careful with your escaping when using this function as any SQL injection attack has a much broader possible affect.

Comment: `mysql_multi_query()` should be `mysql*i*_multi_query()`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score -3):

or perhaps you could try this...

```
$query1 ="UPDATE name SET money = money + 1;";
$query2 ="UPDATE surname SET money = money + 1";

mysql_query($query1,$query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. The second parameter of mysql_query is a `resource`, not `string`.