# Why does combining my SQL queries into one not work?

Tags: php, mysql

These two PHP MySQL queries work.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM videos WHERE id='10';");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE videoId='10';");
```

This single query fails due to a MySQL syntax error pertinent to the latter DELETE operation.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM videos WHERE id='10';DELETE FROM comments WHERE videoId='10';");
```

I've stared hard and can't see the syntax error. What is it?

Comment: are you sure you can have multiple commands in one query?

Comment: similar to that other question, but this one is much more concise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple queries with `mysql_query`. If you really want to (security risk!), use `mysql_multi_query`. (And you should use the newer `mysqli_*` functions). It's a good idea two embed those two calls in a transaction.

But this looks a lot like you really want to define [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). I highly recommend them, if you are already using InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it a security risk to run many queries at once? And indeed, I'm trying to enforce foreign key constraints.

Comment: Security risk, if you use user supplied data in your queries and fail to escape a single value (sql injections). This cannot happen with prepared statements, but I don't think prepared statements allow multiple queries with a single command either.

Answer (score 3):

Not supported by mysql_query see [How can I put two queries in one mysql_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988921/how-can-i-put-two-queries-in-one-mysql-query) use http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query

Answer (score 1):

Multiples queries are not supported in this function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php