# Inserting into two table simultaneously sharing same id

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Please i have a little problem here. the below code i wrote was meant to insert into two tables simultaneously but it those not work. but if i remove the second INSERT the first INSERT will work dont know whats wrong. ITs meant insert in the first table and also collect the last Insert Id of the First table to the Second table. What did i do wrong

```
<?php
  $english_name = $_POST['EnglishName'];
  $tel_number = $_POST['TelNumber'];
  $email_address = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
  $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
  $age = $_POST['Age'];
  $region = $_POST['Region'];

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("fruitmarket");

  $query="INSERT INTO data (english_name, tel_number, email_address, gender,         age, region) VALUES (";
  $query.="'".$english_name."', ";
  $query.="'".$tel_number."', ";
  $query.="'".$email_address."', ";
  $query.="'".$gender."', ";
  $query.="'".$age."', ";
  $query.="'".$region."')";

  $query .= "INSERT INTO data_category (id, english_name)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$english_name');";


  mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');

  echo "Record is inserted."; 
?>
```

Comment: It will not work because it became an invalid query after you concatenated another query in `$query`, read more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988921/how-can-i-put-two-queries-in-one-mysql-query). And consider changing to mysqli or PDO, as mysql is already deprecated

Comment: Then can you help me change it to Mysqli i dont really understand PDO

Comment: Sorry but you need to learn it of your own, SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: Why not make two `mysql_query()` instead?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Can you share why you want to run those two insert statements simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry but tot stackoverflow.com is here to help people in any way possible as long as its possible ? or are you indirectly telling me my understanding of  stackoverflow.com is wrong or that you dont know it ?

Comment: because my android app market fetchs value from the two tables to display category. So Data table id must correspond to data-category table

Comment: @EdwardWalker check answer below

Comment: Am receiving this error 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\markeet\olx\test\update2.php on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\markeet\olx\test\update2.php on line 35
Errormessage:

Comment: post your lastes code

Answer (score 1):

its almost 2018, so please stop using depreciated and removed `mysql_*` functions use PDO/mysqli with prepared statements.

I have re-written your code with prepared statements, please follow these links :

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "fruitmarket";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = "INSERT INTO data (english_name,tel_number,email_address,gender,age,region) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$sql = $conn->prepare($stmt);
$sql->bind_param("ssssis", $english_name, $tel_number, $email_address, $gender, $age, $region);

if ($sql->execute()) {

    $id = $sql->insert_id;

    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_category (id, english_name) VALUES(?,?)");
    $insert->bind_param("is", $id, $english_name);

    if ($insert->execute()) {

        echo "data inserted successfully";
    } else {

        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
} else {

    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

A prepared statement is a feature used to execute the same (or similar) SQL statements repeatedly with high efficiency.

Prepared statements basically work like this:

- Prepare: An SQL statement template is created and sent to the
  database. Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters
  (labeled "?"). Example: INSERT INTO myTabvle VALUES(?, ?, ?)
- The database parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on
  the SQL statement template, and stores the result without executing
  it
- Execute: At a later time, the application binds the values to the
  parameters, and the database executes the statement. The application
  may execute the statement as many times as it wants with different
  values Compared to executing SQL statements directly, prepared
  statements have three main advantages:
- Prepared statements reduces parsing time as the preparation on the
  query is done only once (although the statement is executed multiple
  times)
- Bound parameters minimize bandwidth to the server as you need send
  only the parameters each time, and not the whole query
- Prepared statements are very useful against SQL injections, because
  parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different
  protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement
  template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot
  occur.

Comment: Am getting error 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\markeet\olx\test\update2.php on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\markeet\olx\test\update2.php on line 35
Errormessage:

Comment: you need to use the code I gave u all of it @EdwardWalker delete ur code and use this one

Comment: AM USING ALL OF IT

Comment: @EdwardWalkerlet me see how u use it

Comment: i just copied it and passed it and changed the database user. the only mistake i made is not to include that its used by form i mean registration form pass value to it so it will upload it to database

Answer (score 1):

I tested the above code and noticed you just need just to add and change some code see my below example

```
<?php
  $english_name = $_POST['EnglishName'];
  $tel_number = $_POST['TelNumber'];
  $email_address = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
  $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
  $age = $_POST['Age'];
  $region = $_POST['Region'];

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("fruitmarket");

  $query="INSERT INTO data (english_name, tel_number, email_address, gender, age, region) VALUES (";
  $query.="'".$english_name."', ";
  $query.="'".$tel_number."', ";
  $query.="'".$email_address."', ";
  $query.="'".$gender."', ";
  $query.="'".$age."', ";
  $query.="'".$region."')";

  mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');

  echo "Record is inserted."; 

  $query= "INSERT INTO data_category (id, english_name)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$english_name');";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');

  echo "Record is inserted.";
?>
```

test it to check if it will work